# Java: Make one item of a jcombobox unselectable(like for a sub-caption) and edit font of that item

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

How to make one item in a combobox **unselectable** because I **need to separate items in a combobox with a sub-topic**.

And is it possible to modify the font of that particular item individually?

```
        jComboBox_btech_course.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 14));
        jComboBox_btech_course.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Select Course" }));
        jComboBox_btech_course.setName("");

private class theHandler implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) 
    {
        //BTech courses

        if(jComboBox_mtech_dept.getSelectedItem().equals("Civil Engineering"))
        {
            jComboBox_btech_course.removeAllItems();
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Building Construction");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Principle And Practice");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Surveying");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Engineering Geology");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Structural Analysis");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Hydraulic Engineering");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Environmental Engineering");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Structural Design");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Geotechnical Engineering");
            /*This item has to be unselectable*/
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("***Sub-topic***");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Transportation Engineering");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Foundation Engineering");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Estimation & Valuation");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Hydrology & Flood Control");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("System Analysis, Project Planning And Construction Management");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Irrigation Engineering");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Computer Application in Civil Engineering");
            jComboBox_btech_course.addItem("Planning, Design & Detailing");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Foreword: In the proposed solution I assume that you want to disable items that start with `"**"`. You can change this logic to whatever you want to. In an improved version the `MyComboModel` class (see below) may even store which items are disabled allowing arbitrary items to be marked disabled.

Solution to your question involves 2 things:

### 1. Disallow selecting items which you want to be disabled

For this you can use a custom [`ComboBoxModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html), and override its [`setSelectedItem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ComboBoxModel.html#setSelectedItem-java.lang.Object-) method to do nothing if the item to be selected is a disabled one:

```
class MyComboModel extends DefaultComboBoxModel<String> {
    public MyComboModel() {}
    public MyComboModel(Vector<String> items) {
        super(items);
    }
    @Override
    public void setSelectedItem(Object item) {
        if (item.toString().startsWith("**"))
            return;
        super.setSelectedItem(item);
    };
}
```

And you can set this new model by passing an instance of it to the `JComboBox` constructor:

```
JComboBox<String> cb = new JComboBox<>(new MyComboModel());
```

### 2. Display disabled items with different font

For this you have to use a custom [`ListCellRenderer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) and in [`getListCellRendererComponent()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html#getListCellRendererComponent-javax.swing.JList-E-int-boolean-boolean-) method you can configure different visual appearance for disabled and enabled items:

```
Font f1 = cb.getFont();
Font f2 = new Font("Tahoma", 0, 14);

cb.setRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value,
            int index, boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {
        if (value instanceof JComponent)
            return (JComponent) value;

        boolean itemEnabled = !value.toString().startsWith("**"); 

        super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index,
                isSelected && itemEnabled, cellHasFocus);

        // Render item as disabled and with different font:
        setEnabled(itemEnabled);
        setFont(itemEnabled ? f1 : f2);

        return this;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get what you need, you need to implement `ComboBoxEditor`.

In this way, you can decide what you want to do in your case, or in any other cases

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom `ItemListener` via

```
addItemListener(ItemListener aListener)
```

and in that method disable selection or switch selection to item above or so.